# How to prove $\binom{n+1}{m+1}=\binom{0}{m}+\binom{1}{m}+\dots+\binom{n}{m}$ combinatorially

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, recreational-mathematics

How can we prove combinatorially

$$\binom{n+1}{m+1}=\binom{0}{m}+\binom{1}{m}+\dots+\binom{n}{m}$$

I can get LHS by asking: How many ways can we form an $m+1$ person committee from a group of $n+1$ people. But I can't get RHS with this question.

I think I can get RHS by asking: How many ways can we form an $m$ person committee from a group of at most $n$ people. But I can't get LHS with this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove ${n - 1 \choose k - 1} + {n - 2 \choose k - 1} + {n - 3 \choose k - 1} + \dots + {k - 1 \choose k - 1} = {n \choose k}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451745/prove-n-1-choose-k-1-n-2-choose-k-1-n-3-choose-k-1)

Comment: The formula is false (or meaningless) . It should be:$$\binom{n+1}{m+1}=\binom{m}{m}+\binom{m+1}{m}+\dots+\binom{n}{m}.$$

Comment: If only  had a penny for each time this question has been asked.

Comment: On the other hand I've gained like 200 rep for this question over the years.

Comment: @Bernard It is the same formula under the convention that $\binom{k}{m} = 0$ for $k < m$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1490794/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count how many ways to select $m+1$ people from a line of $n+1$ people, by selecting one person at some place (call it $k$), and then select $m$ people from the $k-1$ earlier in the line.

This count is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom{k-1}{m} = \sum\limits_{k=m+1}^{n+1}\binom{k-1}{m}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Pascal's triangle identity
$$
{n+1 \choose m+1} + {n+1 \choose m} = {n+2 \choose m+1}
$$
and induction.

Comment: How is this combinatorial?

Comment: I suppose this is combinatorial in the sense that it would be acceptable in a combinatorics journal.

Comment: Usually combinatorial proof means double counting.